# Repeat First List index value until second loop run and save in CSV using Python

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

```
List1 = ['ROLLER,abc','BOLT,s']

List2 = ['TYPE , ROL,','DMET, LENGTH, THRES Tgg, GRE B, HEAD X,']
```

I want to save the lists data into CSV like this using python

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Roller,abc | Type |
| Roller,abc | Rol |
| Bolt,s | DMET |
| Bolt,s | Lenght |
| Bolt,s | Thress tag |
| Bolt,s | GRE B |
| Bolt,s | Head X |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to use `open` as context manager with `with` operator.
It will close file if `IndexError` exception happens.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i, col_1 in enumerate(List1):
        for col_2 in List2[i].split(','):
            file.write(f"{col_1},{col_2.strip()}\n")
```

Comment: Yes its almost working for me but one problem I am facing is in LIST1 I have list like this LIST['Value,range', 'Check,abd']. So this is spliting into other column but i need it in one column

Comment: @AsharParacha , what program do you use to read this file? If it's excel, you can just use another separator for columns, for example `;`, and select this symbol in export settings.

Comment: In code you need to change last line to `file.write(f"{col_1};{col_2.strip()}\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Quick response without csv module

This is not the best method!

```
list1 = ['ROLLER','BOLT']

list2 = ['TYPE , ROL','DMET, LENGTH, THRES Tgg, GRE B, HEAD X,']

file = open("test.csv", mode="w")
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for y in [_.strip() for _ in list2[i].split(",")]:
        file.write(list1[i] + "," + y+"\n")

file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. It's almost working for me. I am facing a same issue I have some values in list1 like ''' List1 = ['ashar,paracha', 'Alexis,leloup'] I want to save these values as well in a single column.